# nginx prod setup for Clojure WebSocket app

Tags: websocket, clojure, webserver

I'm trying to deploy my first Clojure WebSocket app and I think I'm getting close. I get a good response locally, and it looks like the endpoint wants to face the outside world (I see that the port is open when I run `netstat`), but no response. I'm certain that I have something setup incorrectly in `nginx`.

I currently already host a few other websites on this server, just want to add the necessary config to get requests made to `wss://domain.com:8001` to communicate with my app.

Here is the location entry I'm using now:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Connection "";
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_redirect off;
  access_log /var/www/logs/test.access.log;
  error_log /var/www/logs/test.error.log;
}
```

Could anyone help point me in the right direction? My guess is that I actually have too much in the config, and what's there is probably not correct.

** **EDIT:** ** For interested parties, I put up my working config (based on Erik Dannenberg's answer) in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jacobw56/dd642e574257bfcc788bc0890b9aec29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing two more headers, a minimal working config:

```
location  /  {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    # add the two below
    proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
    proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
    # optional, but helpful if you run into timeouts
    proxy_read_timeout 86400;
}
```

Comment: A version of this seems to be working. Thanks so much, so helpful!